# Button checked with jQuery in Jade issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I read a couple of links and I just can't find the answer to why is it not working.

I need to have a button checked upon loading a page in Jade here is the button code:

```
.radio
    label
      input#camera(type='radio', name="camera", value="1")
      |             Camera
```

and this is the JS:

```
$("#camera").prop("checked", true)
```

I already checked that jQuery is working on my page and that the version for the prop function is above 1.6. 
Thanks to anyone who could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to be set immediately, just set a `checked` attribute in Jade:

```
input#camera(type='radio', name="camera", value="1", checked="checked")
```

Otherwise, make sure that your jQuery code is run when the DOM is ready (ie when all elements are present):

```
$(function() {
  $("#camera").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.. maybe you query the document before it is ready? Would be helpful to see the generated html.

You could try:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#camera").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That above code works as you describe it for me.  I just had to make sure that the formatting of the jade was correct - there was a mixture of spaces/tabs when I copied it.

You could default checked on with jade.

```
input#camera(type="radio", name="camera", value="1", checked="checked")
```